# Undoing the \n escape sequence

Tags: python, escaping

I had a doubt in python programming.
I typed the following code:

`print('Hello\n'*5, end = 'World')`

which gave me an output:
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
World

I knew this was it, but I wanted the World to come on the same last line. Is it possible in anyway?

FYI. I am using Python 3.8

Comment: You could do ```print('Hello\n'*4, 'Hello ', end = 'World\n', sep = '')``` or 
```print('Hello\n'*4, 'Hello World\n', sep = '')```

Answer (score 0):

You could do any of the following

```
print('\nHello '*5, end = 'World') or
print('Hello\n'*4, 'Hello ', end = 'World', sep = '') or
print('Hello\n'*4, 'Hello World\n', sep = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a matter of taste, but I find `end="part of the message"` (and also `sep=`) unpythonic.

I would prefer:

```
print("Hello\n"*4, "Hello World", sep = '')
```

or also:

```
for i in range(4):
    print("Hello")
print("Hello World")
```